# R Shiny: insertUI/removeUI does not work with navbarPage

Tags: r, shiny

This is almost a verbatim copy of the code found here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html

However, simply changing from fluidPage to navbarPage in the UI renders this completely nonfunctional. What needs to be done to make this work?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage('title', 
  
  actionButton('insertBtn', 'Insert'), 
  actionButton('removeBtn', 'Remove'), 
  tags$div(id = 'placeholder') 
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  ## keep track of elements inserted and not yet removed
  inserted <- c()
  
  observeEvent(input$insertBtn, {
    btn <- input$insertBtn
    id <- paste0('txt', btn)
    insertUI(
      selector = '#placeholder',
      ## wrap element in a div with id for ease of removal
      ui = tags$div(
        tags$p(paste('Element number', btn)), 
        id = id
      )
    )
    inserted <<- c(id, inserted)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$removeBtn, {
    removeUI(
      ## pass in appropriate div id
      selector = paste0('#', inserted[length(inserted)])
    )
    inserted <<- inserted[-length(inserted)]
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

There does not seem to be any documentation at all covering how dynamic UIs work with navbarPage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the docs for a `navbarPage` vs. a `fluidPage`:

In a `fluidPage` you could pass

> Elements to include within the page

via the `...` argument, whereas for a `navbarPage` you have to pass none, one or multiple `tabPanel`s:

> tabPanel() elements to include in the page.

Hence, you could fix your issue by wrapping the elements inside a `tabPanel`:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(
  "title",
  tabPanel(
    title = "Tab 1",
    actionButton("insertBtn", "Insert"),
    actionButton("removeBtn", "Remove"),
    tags$div(id = "placeholder")
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick solution! I was playing around with the test code here to explore the issue in my main code and didn't realize tabPanel was required. I thought navbarPage was the issue, but in my main code I had a submitButton within in the same tabPanel and realized the page only updated when I clicked the submit button. It probably has to do with HTML form submissions registering as events as well, but I can work around this with an action button of a different color.